# How to generate a random string with symbols

Tags: python, symbols, generated

My code:

```
import random
import string
random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits ) for n in range(12)])
```

So far it prints a string which contains uppercase, lowercase letters and numbers, but I don't know how to make it print symbols as well.

Comment: `string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()_'` add em to the mix

Comment: what do u mean by symbols? Any character in unicode ? or just from ascii ?

Comment: I'm guessing `string.printable` isn't what you want because it includes newline, tab, etc?

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
import random
import string
random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation ) for n in range(12)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
import random
import string
random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits  ) for n in 
range(12)])
print(random)`
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random string we need to use the following two Python modules.

- String module which contains various string constant which contains
  the ASCII characters of all cases. String module contains separate
  constants for lowercase, uppercase letters, digits, and special
  characters.
- random module to perform the random generations.

  Let see steps to generate a random string of a fixed length of n.
- Use the string constant string.ascii_lowercase to get all the
  lowercase letter in a single string.
- The string.ascii_lowercase constant contains all lowercase letters.
  I.e., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' Run for loop n number of times to
  pick a single character from a string constant using a random.choice
  method and add it to the string variable using a join method. The
  choice method used to choose the single character from a list
- For example, Suppose you want a random string of length 6 then we can
  execute a random.choice() method 6 times to pick a single letter from
  the string.ascii_lowercase and add it to the string variable.

Let see the code now.

```
import random
import string

def randomStringwithDigitsAndSymbols(stringLength=10):
    """Generate a random string of letters, digits and special characters """
    password_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
    return ''.join(random.choice(password_characters) for i in range(stringLength))

print("Generating Random String password with letters, digits and special characters ")
print ("First Random String ", randomStringwithDigitsAndSymbols() )
print ("Second Random String", randomStringwithDigitsAndSymbols(10) )
print ("Third Random String", randomStringwithDigitsAndSymbols(10) )
```

Output:

```
Generating Random String password with letters, digits and special characters 
First Random String password  qKDhC++T(4
Second Random String password  U+(ew5a[#U
Third Random String password  uf-g,s6'pX
```

Use this link for more details [Click here](https://pynative.com/python-generate-random-string/)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly another variant:

```
import random
import string
random_string = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation ) for n in range(12)])
```

In this case you do not redefine `random` form library.

Comment: this is a good point

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but you can weight them to have more letters and numbers and fewer punctuation characters like this:

```
import random
import string

pw = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.ascii_letters + string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.digits + string.digits + string.punctuation ) for n in range(12)])
print(pw)
```

Comment: use random.sample instead of loops